# Java: using get method with an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing, get, return

I was hoping someone would be able to give me some help with the correct way of returning an array with a get method.

```
public void setScores (int Scores[])
{
    this.scores = Scores;
}
```

I can set the Array no problem, I can't figure out a way to return the array to print.

```
public int [] getScores ()
{

    for (int index =0; index <5; index ++)
    {
        System.out.println("Score"+x +"is" +this.scores[index]);
        x=x+1;
    }
    return scores;
}
```

I know the above code will **not** work because I am simply returning the whole array, not the elements within it.

What I am trying to do is, display each element of the array to console:

```
System.out.println( "Player "+playName+"'s Scores are: \n"+Players.getScores());
```

Do I need to use a for loop on the above part?

Appreciate the help, 
thanks

Comment: I know the print within the for loop should not be there, I was just making sure the array was actually present to be worked with.

Comment: What is your exact problem? do you want to return the array, just one value of it, or print out every specific value. It´s not getting clear from your whole question

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "because I am simply returning the whole array, not the elements within it"

Comment: If you want to just print your array, you can do so lazily with `Arrays.toString(scores)`. If you want to return the array itself, then you're already doing so correctly.

Comment: It's also not clear what you know about the player, or where you're trying to print the player's scores from. Why don't you have a `Player` class which has both the name and the score? Writing a short but *complete* example would make this question much, much clearer.

Comment: In addition to this, rather use `for(int index = 0;index<this.scores.length;index++)` This is more safe if you are about to change the size of the array

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I have a player class which receives the array from another class called "GuessingGame". I am then trying to return this array's elements only back to the guessing game class within a print statement. This is for an assignment that I have to follow fairly strictly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you need the results you would call the get method and then iterate over the array something like

```
int[] result = getScores();
System.out.println("Player "+playName+"'s Scores are:")
for(int n: result){
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a print loop inside of getScores, put a for loop in whatever method prints the array, and have it construct a string containing the elements.

Returning the array

```
public int [] getScores ()
{
    return scores;
}
```

In main method

```
int[] array = obj.getScores();
StringBuilder elements = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0;i < array.length -1;i++){
    elements.append(array[i] +",");
}
elements.append(array[array.length-1]);
System.out.println( "Player "+playName+"'s Scores are: \n"+elements.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to use a `for` or a `while` loop to display each element of an array to the console.

Something like:

```
int[] score = getScores();
for(int i = 0; i < score.length; i++){
    System.out.println(score[i]);
}
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

you want to display the scores or return the scores. If you just want display then there is no need to return the scores.

- x is not initialized.
- you can apply loop till the length of the array not just 5.
- you can simply put the array inside the println method. it will automatically call the toString() method.

  System.out.println("Players scores are : " + this.scores);

you can use for each loop too although it works with Wrapper classes, but conversion will be taken care due to the autoboxing property.